# react-i18next and replacing placeholder keys with components

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-intl, react-i18next

Previously I was using `react-intl` and was able to set placeholders for items which would be replaced with components, e.g. `{br}` with `<br />`.

I'm currently getting errors when using `react-i18next` and `i18next-icu` where I'm trying to do:

```js
// Using Intl format (via i18next-icu)
{
  "test": "Replace with a{br}line-break. {button}"
}
```

```js
t("test", { br: <br />, button: <button>Click me!</button> });
```

```js
// Outputted translated text
Replace with a[object Object]line-break. [object Object]
```

Is it actually possible to do this using `i18next`/`i18next-icu` ? If not, what would be another method to insert components into the translated string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure react i18next like this in your i18n.js to support basic tags:

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

i18n
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        fallbackLng: "en",
        react: {
            // https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#trans-props
            transSupportBasicHtmlNodes: true,
            transKeepBasicHtmlNodesFor: ["br", "strong", "b", "i"],
        }
    });

export default i18n;
```

Then you can as @jamuhl said use the  component like this:

```
const keyInTranslationJsonFile=`My text that can be <b>{{boldPlaceholder}}</b>`;
<Trans i18nKey={keyInTranslationJsonFile}>{{boldPlaceholder: "bold"}}</Trans>
```

I just noticed that it's not possible to alert a Trans component. As far as I know you cannot make something bold with the `t()` function or use any tags. But you can still use normal placeholders at least.

Like this:

```
const keyInTranslationJsonFile=`You've selected the max of {{selectLimit}} elements`;
alert(
    t(keyInTranslationJsonFile, {
        selectLimit: selectLimit,
    })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component is there to include react components (like also br, strong, ...) into your translations

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, however it's not directly portable from my existing ICU translations, nor is it entirely helpful as well. It's harder to get a non-technical translator to use `<0></0>` to mark a `<br />` than it is for them to either use a `<br />` or `{br}`.

Comment: Since `v10.4.0` you can use the [`transKeepBasicHtmlNodesFor`](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#using-for-less-than-br-greater-than-and-other-simple-html-elements-in-translations-v-10-4-0) option to interpolate basic HTML elements like `<br />` in translation strings; no need for `<0></0>`.